# CodeIgniter language selection

Tags: php, codeigniter

I want the user to select his language from any sub page on my website. The best solution, to store each user language are sessions.

My website default language is English, but how should I load other language that user select?
I guess I should do it like this:

`$this->lang->load('my_language_file', $this->session->userdata('language'));`

But this way, I'd have to load the language in every controller.
Isn't there a way, to select user language from session globally? So I could use `$this->lang->line('some-message');` in every place on my website?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Either do a

```
$CI =& get_instance();
$CI->lang->load('my_language_file', $CI->session->userdata('language'));
```

in the beginning of a custom [**helper**](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/helpers.html) and have it [**autoloaded**](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/autoloader.html) in your config/autoload.php.

Else you can do it through [**hooks**](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/hooks.html).
Basicly use

```
$CI =& get_instance();
$CI->lang->load('my_language_file', $CI->session->userdata('language'));
```

here aswell inside the __construct(), and have the Hook Point `post_controller_constructor`.

This will make you include the lang file in all controllers. However it's up to you how much lang-text you want to load automaticly, since it exhausts the server even if only to a small extent.

Comment: Well, default language (English) is loading automatically, so how does it matter, if I will load English file for each user and other language for other users?

Comment: It doesn't matter I suppose. Why would it?

Comment: You wrote: `[..]since it exhausts the server even if only to a small extent.`

Comment: It's nothing you really need to care about. In theiry it's just better to load relevant lang file to relevant controller since less memory is used in the execution of the code. But this only matters on really large language files, so might not matter at all in your case.